# Etale local subscheme cut out by an equation

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In SGA 7 Exposé XVI, Proposition 1.13, it is said:
[image]

> Case 1. $n=\dim X_s=2m-1$.
> The problem is local for the étale topology on $X$. One can then suppose that $X_s$ is the subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}_S$ defined by a equation ......

Why can one suppose that?